# How to use importxml to a website that requires log in?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I already known how to use the importxml to import a certain text from a website to Google Sheets. However, this website `experience.aiesec.org` requires log in.
I have the username and password of course. I also have already log in to this website in by browser. But when using importxml, it acknowledge me as haven't log in yet. I also used the syntax `https://username:password@url` but it does not work at all.
Any suggestion pls? Or I should use another service instead of Google Sheets?

Comment: I haven't been in your current scenario yet but I think these kind of operations fits the use of [Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview?csw=1) rather than Sheet API. Actually found a blog post about using [XMLIMPORT and Apps Script](https://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/#chapter3) to make your life easier. Maybe you can try to create your on [Apps Script Add-On](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) or make the file public.

Answer (score 3):

The `importXML()` function runs from Google's servers not from your browser, therefore, will only work with websites that are publicly available and do not require authentication.

There are 2 ways to automate the import of data from experience.aiesec.org using Google Sheets:

1. **IF** [*experience.aiesec.org*](https://experience.aiesec.org) **HAVE** public API
   you can code a custom, time-triggered or event-triggered function in Google Scripts that will authenticate using whatever *aiesec.org*'s API is requiring, then fetch the data and write it into your Google spreadsheet.
2. **IF** [*experience.aiesec.org*](https://experience.aiesec.org) **DOES NOT HAVE** public API
   you can use a Chrome Extension like [Data Scraper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-scraper-easy-web-scr/nndknepjnldbdbepjfgmncbggmopgden) to periodically scrape the site into a CSV file and then import the CSV into your Google spreadsheet.

Comment: Would you be more specific on the first option ?